# Is $SL_n(\mathbb R)$ group of rotation matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

The special linear group $SL_n(\mathbb R)$ is a group of $n\times n$ matrix of determinant 1. But we know that every rotation mapping in $\mathbb R^n$ is represented by a matrix with determinant 1. But I wonder if every matrix in $SL_n(\mathbb R)$ is a rotation ? I hope someone will enlight me this. Thank you

Comment: Can you define for us what a rotation of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is when $n \geq 3$?

Comment: Start by working out the 2-dimensional case, say, looking at diagonal or upper triangular, matrices.

Comment: Rotations are also orthogonal matrices.

Comment: hmm, so group of rotation matrix is $SL_n(\mathbb R)\cap O(n)$ ?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by a rotation in higher dimensions. What is your definition?

Comment: I haven't found any other definitions of it except the definition using an orthogonal matrix with determinant 1. I wish I could find another definition of rotation in $\mathbb R^n$ using the spherical coordinates

Comment: The group of rotation matrices in the standard sense is indeed the set you describe. They can equivalently be defined as the set of of linear maps $R$ that satisfy $\|T\vec{v}\|=\|\vec{v}\|$ for any vector $\vec v \in \mathbb{R}^d$. In spherical coordinates, this amounts to all linear maps that don't change the radial $r$ component.

Comment: Then the answer to your question is tautologically positive. Some people require rotations to have codimension 2 fixed point sets (and be orthogonal).